# Password validation using Regex in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. User Name Field should accept Alphanumeric
2. Maximum characters will be 16 and Starting should be character not a digit

   ```
   var usernametest=$("#userName").val()
   var letters = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$/; 

   if(usernametest.match(letters))
   {
       alert('accepted');
   }
   else
   {
       alert('not accepted');
   }
   ```

The above code is working fine for accepting alphanumeric character.
But it also accepts the starting digit as number.

I want starting digit must be an alphabet. I am new to regular expressions please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your regex like this,

```
var letters = /^(?=.*\d)[a-z][a-z\d]{7,15}$/i;
```

or

```
var letters = /^(?=[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$/; 

                  ^           ^
                  |           |-Ensures atleast one digit
           satisfies first char to be alphabet condition
```

Comment: or `var letters = /^(?=[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]{8,16}$/i; `